# Range of integers returned by glGenBuffers?

Tags: opengl, buffers

I'm developing a general Mesh class with the help of [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/). In the example he creates a class which assumes that you want to generate a VAO, VBO, and an EBO but I don't usually use EBOs so I only want to generate an EBO under certain circumstances. So if I decide not to generate an EBO then I want to set my EBO to a number which cannot be generated by `glGenBuffers`.

```
// Draw Mesh
glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

if(EBO not in range generated by glGenBuffers)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
} else {
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

My question is what is the range that a buffer object's name can be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OpenGL spec, any integer other than zero can be a potential name. Zero is the only value that's guaranteed not to be an object name.

Relevant quote from [the spec](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf):

> **2.6.1.1    Name Spaces, Name Generation, and Object Creation**
>
> Each object type has a corresponding *name space*.  Names of objects are represented by unsigned integers of type `uint`.  The name zero is reserved by the GL; for some object types, zero names a *default object* of that type, and in others zero will never correspond to an actual instance of that object type.
>
> Names of most types of objects are created by *generating* unused names using commands starting with **Gen** followed by the object type.  For example, the command **GenBuffers** returns one or more previously unused buffer object names.

Comment: Do you mean any integer or any unsigned integer?

Comment: @Archmede The type of names is unsigned integer, so that's what I mean.